# Parentheses in the set $\Omega \subseteq\mathbf R\times \mathbf R^n$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, elementary-set-theory

> Consider a system of differential equations of first order with $n$ equations
> $$
> \mathbf x'(t)=\mathbf f(t,\mathbf x) 
> $$
> and the initial condition $\mathbf x(t_0)=\mathbf x_0$.
> Here $\mathbf f(t,\mathbf x)$ is a continuous function from some open, connected set $\Omega \subseteq\mathbf R\times \mathbf R^n$ to $\mathbf R^n$.

Does  $\Omega \subseteq\mathbf R\times \mathbf R^n$ mean

$$
(\Omega \subseteq\mathbf R )\times \mathbf R^n  \tag 1
$$
Or
$$
\Omega \subseteq(\mathbf R\times \mathbf R^n) \tag 2
$$
?

Update:

If $\Omega \subseteq(\mathbf R\times \mathbf R^n)$ is correct, isn't $\Omega \subseteq\mathbf R\times \mathbf R^n$ ambiguous?

Comment: (1) doesn't make any sense. $\Omega\subseteq R$ is a logical statement, not a set. You can't take the cartesian product of a statement with a set.

Comment: What does $(\Omega\subset\mathbb R)\times\mathbb R^n$ even mean? The latter interpretation is the only reasonable one, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why it shouldn't mean $\Omega\subseteq(\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^n)$, seeing as:

- this is the standard way to read $X\subseteq A\times B$;
- it makes sense in the context;
- the other candidate is highly non-standard (not to say unheard of), and I daresay any decent writer would spend his time articulating "$\Omega\times \Bbb R^n$ with $\Omega\subseteq \Bbb R$".

For the record, keep in mind that modern mathematical language is modelled over (present-day) Indo-European languages. To the best of my knowledge these languages organise their proposition around the system subject-predicate-complement. This means that grammatically there is a very strict separation between the *verb*, which is a word that can only be used as the part of the sentence ("predicate") expressing the action, and the *sustantives*, which are the objects that may *do* ("subject") or *receive* / *partake of* ("complements") the action. In $X\subseteq A\times B$ this machinery comes into play because "$\subseteq$" replaces the predicate "*being subset of*", whereas "$X$" and "$A\times B$" indicate objects which are respectively subject and complement of the sentence. Therefore "$\subseteq$" is a verb, and "$X$" and "$A\times B$" are sustantives: this is effectively their indivisible nature as grammatical entities. An interpretation such as your $(X\subseteq A)\times B$ is not sound in this context because it mixes those things: in fact it cannot be interpreted as a standalone sentence or group of sentences, but I don't want to go into further detail.

Comment: Can you explain further why "$\Omega\times \Bbb R^n$ with $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb R$" doesn't make sense? Does it make sense if we instead had "$\Bbb R\times \Omega$ with $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb R^n$"? I think I have seen exmaples with "consider the function $g: \Omega \subseteq \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$", which I think is correct (?).

Comment: @JDoeDoe "$\Omega\times\Bbb R^n$ with $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb R$" would make sense there, and so would $\Bbb R\times\Omega$. It's just that it has been written otherwise. $g:\Omega\subseteq\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is a notation in use for a function $g$ from a subset $\Omega$ of $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: This is an abuse of notation, meaning: $g:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R$

Comment: @Gae.S. Hi! English is not my native language, so if I understand you correctly, you mean: Instead  of "$(\Omega \subseteq\Bbb R) \times \Bbb R^n$" we write 
$$
\Omega\times\Bbb R^n \quad  \text{with } \Omega \subseteq\Bbb R \tag 1
$$
And instead of  "$\Bbb R \times (\Omega \subseteq \Bbb R^n)$" we write:
$$
\Bbb R \times \Omega \quad \text{with } \Omega \subseteq\Bbb R^n \tag 2
$$?

Comment: Yes, we write those in common language (I presume in yours as well).

Answer (score 2):

Try to consider the following for real numbers $x,y,z$:
$$x\leq y\cdot z.$$

Does $(x\leq y)\cdot z$ make sense? No. You're multiplying a real number with a truth value. This is a type mismatch that you can't quite recover, unless explicitly explaining how you are interpreting $\leq$ and $+$ to be compatible this way. But if you weren't told explicitly that this is something that is allowed (in the context of your textbook), you will not under $(x\leq y)\cdot z$.

Similarly, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbf{R\times R}^n$ only that it involves sets. But the fundamentals are the same.